# Possible to pass a model to output in a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I would like to select a feature and model (from sidebar dropdown menu's) and be able to pass the model to a specific output where I print the summary of the model and show how well the model fits graphically. I currently have a reactive function in server.R that checks which input$model is selected, then fits the model and returns it. When I try to call this reactive function from output$evaluation I get errors. I'm not sure how to do this.

```
# server.R

#...

fitter <- reactive({

  df_clean <- dataset() # another reactive function that selects the dataset to be used
  rownames(df_clean) <- df_clean$timestamp
  df_clean$timestamp <- NULL

  if (input$Model == 'Linear'){
    fit <- lm(input$Response ~., data=df_clean)
  }
  #... more if statements checking for other model types

  return(fit)

})

# Model Evaluation

output$Evaluation <- renderPrint({

  summary(fitter())

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the string in your `lm` call to a `formula`, using `as.formula`.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
    shinyUI(
      fluidPage(
        inputPanel(
            selectInput("Model", "Model:", choices=c("Linear", "Other")),
            selectInput("Response", "Response:", choices=c("mpg", "disp"))
        ),
        tableOutput("Evaluation")
      )
    ),
    shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
        fitter <- reactive({
            df_clean <- mtcars

            if (input$Model == 'Linear'){
                fit <- lm(as.formula(paste(input$Response, "~.")), data=df_clean)
            }
            return(fit)
        })
        output$Evaluation <- renderTable({
            summary(fitter())
        })
    })
)
```